# MTOM/XOP support in BizTalk 2006 R2?

Tags: wcf, biztalk, mtom, biztalk2006r2, xop

We are currently working on an BizTalk solution that should return binary data as a XOP attachement through an webservice request. BizTalk have MTOM support through WCF adapters, but I can't figure out if BizTalk also supports XOP?

(I found an blog post on [BizTalk attachment patterns](http://seroter.wordpress.com/biztalk-and-wcf-part-iv-attachment-patterns/), but that not give me the preferred solution)

We are using BizTalk 2006 R2, Visual Studio 2005

Comment: I found a stackoverflow answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487043/enable-streaming-in-biztalk-wcf-adapter - I'll try this approach.